# Javascript to exclude string input on .each

Tags: javascript, input, each

I'm working to add features to some example code and am having some difficulty. The original code is an alarm, and I am adding the option to include a message. Here are the relative snippets. Full code is here http://codepen.io/stmoule/pen/WwJymN.

Relative HTML

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div id="alarm-dialog">
    <h2>Set alarm after</h2>
    <label class="hours">
                Hours
                <input type="number" id="inputTimeValue" value="0" min="0" />
            </label>
    <label class="minutes">
                Minutes
                <input type="number" id="inputTimeValue" value="0" min="0" />
            </label>
    <label class="seconds">
                Seconds
                <input type="number" id="inputTimeValue" value="0" min="0" />
            </label>

<!--     Begin where I added -->
    <div class="messageBox">
      <label class="message">
                    Message
                    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Include a message?" />
                </label>
    </div>
<!--     End of my addition -->
    <div class="button-holder">
      <a id="alarm-set" class="button blue">Set</a>
      <a id="alarm-clear" class="button red">Clear</a>
    </div>
    <a class="close">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Relative Javascript

```
alarm_set.click(function() {

    var valid = true,
      after = 0,
      to_seconds = [3600, 60, 1];

    dialog.find('input').each(function(i) {

      // Using the validity property in HTML5-enabled browsers:

      if (this.validity && !this.validity.valid) {

        // The input field contains something other than a digit,
        // or a number less than the min value

        valid = false;
        this.focus();

        return false;
      }

      after += to_seconds[i] * parseInt(parseInt(this.value));

    });

    if (!valid) {
      alert('Please enter a valid number!');
      return;
    }

    if (after < 1) {
      alert('Please choose a time in the future!');
      return;
    }

    alarm_counter = after;
    dialog.trigger('hide');
  });
```

What I believe is happening is the JS is finding all the inputs, which was great until I added the text input. I tried adding a for loop that limits it to the first three, tried adding '&& isNaN' to the if statement in the JS, tried using ID's/names to the dialog.find('input'). While I've googled this and searched here extensively, I feel like I've mentally come up the solution but am having trouble applying it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to stop your .each from not doing anything to text inputs, try not selecting them at all using the jQuery :not() selector. Rather than saying

```
$('input').each()
```

you could say

```
$('input:not(:text)');
```

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Changed dialog.find('input').each(function(i) { .... }); to  $(dialog.find('input:not(:text)').each(function(i) { .... })); and it worked very nicely. Thank you Caleb.